# Google Maps Autocomplete API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

This code was working for me but now even I have tried a new key but it isn't working. It doesn't show the suggestions to autocomplete 
Main purpose is to create a textfield with google map autocomplete functionality.

Comment: It must work with your API key. Please check that you have enabled that service from console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your api console and add below services.
[image]

Also make sure you are using API key.